# Filter Foreign Key Drop Down Field Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 3 tables Student, K8Points, and TeacherClass . The table students tracks all student data information and you can assign them to a classroom, points tracks the points they earned for the day, classroom table is where you create the classroom names. What i want to accomplish is when you are logged in to /k8_points_classroom/1? page, there is a drop down field of students. 1 at the end of the classroom is the classroom id. The field student_name should only show the kids in that particular class, how do i filter that field ? Right now it just pulls up every student in the database. Thanks for the help .

Model

```
class TeacherClass(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default= "")
    teacher_name = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default= "")


    class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Teacher Class Room"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name


class Student(models.Model):
    studentpsid= models.CharField(primary_key = True , default = "", max_length = 50, unique = True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    student_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = "")
    home_room = models.CharField(max_length = 3, default = "")
    counseling_goal = models.TextField(max_length = 255)
    class_name = models.ManyToManyField(TeacherClass)
    image =models.ImageField(default ="default.png", upload_to='student_pics')


class K8Points(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today) 
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(TeacherClass, on_delete = models.PROTECT, default = "",)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default ="" ,) 
    week_of = models.IntegerField(default=weeknumber)
    day = models.CharField(max_length= 10, default = dayofweek)
    TIME_FRAME_CHOICES = [
        (None, 'PLEASE SELECT TIME FRAME'),  
        (1, '(1.) 8:45AM - 9:00AM'),
        (2, '(2.) 9:00AM - 9:30AM'),
        (3, '(3.) 9:30AM - 10:00AM'),
        (4, '(4.) REC. I 10:00AM -10:10AM'),
        (5, '(5.) 10:10AM-10:40AM'),
        (6, '(6.) 10:40AM-11:10AM'),
        (7, '(7.) 11:10AM-11:40AM'),
        (8, '(8.) LUNCH 11:40AM-12:00PM'),
        (9, '(9.) REC. II 12:00PM-12:20PM'),
        (10, '(10.) 12:20PM-12:50PM'),
        (11,'(11.) 12:50PM-1:20PM'),
        (12,'(12.) 1:20PM-1:50PM'),
        (13,'(13.) 1:50PM-2:20PM'),
        (14,'(14.) REC. III 2:20PM-2:30PM'),
    ]
    time_frame = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_FRAME_CHOICES,)
    behavior = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ])
    academic = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ] )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "K8-Points"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

Form

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.classid = kwargs.pop('classid', None)
          super(K8Points_ClassroomForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
          self.fields['date'].disabled = True
          self.fields['day'].disabled = True
          self.fields['week_of'].disabled = True
          self.fields['class_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True  
          getstudents = Student.objects.filter(class_name = self.classid).order_by('student_name')
          self.fields['student_name'].queryset= getstudents.all().order_by('student_name')
```

View

```
@login_required
def K8_Points_Classroom(request, classid):

    if request.method == "GET":

        date = datetime.date.today()
        students = Student.objects.filter(class_name=classid).order_by('student_name')
        class_name = TeacherClass.objects.get(id=classid)
        form = K8Points_ClassroomForm(classid = class_name.id)
        request.session['my_class_id'] = classid
        return render(request, 'points/k8_points_classroom.html', {'form': form, 'students': students, 'class_name': class_name, 'date': date , 'classid': classid})
```

Comment: This works but if i hardcode the id in but i cant grab the id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the class in as a parameter to the form in the view, then adjust the student_name field's queryset to filter down to that class' students.

```
class K8PointsClassroomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, class_=None, **kwargs):
          super (K8Points_ClassroomForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs )
          self.fields['date'].disabled = True
          self.fields['day'].disabled = True
          self.fields['week_of'].disabled = True
          # Limit the fields queryset to that of the class's students.
          self.fields['student_name'].queryset = class_.student_set.all()
```

Edit:

Here's the view I was trying to explain:

```
@login_required
def K8_Points_Classroom(request, classid):
    class_name = TeacherClass.objects.get(id=classid)
    form = K8Points_ClassroomForm(class_=class_name)
```

Comment: Im confused , so am i making my queryset in the view and the posting it to the forms.py ?

Comment: I posted my view just now so you can see it.

Comment: No, you pass the class instance into the form's constructor.

Comment: Im lost , can you just write it out for me so i can see it.

Comment: `form = K8Points_ClassroomForm(class_=class_instance)`

Comment: i understand the logic about the class instance etc but im not following where the code has to go. Is all this code going just in the forms.py ?

Comment: This is what i get when i add that code.   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'student_set'

Comment: You didn't pass in the TeacherClass instance correctly.

Comment: I just posted what i have in my code , it works but i cant get the class id from the html. If i put 'classid', 1 it will pull all students in class id 1

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant to be copied and pasted directly, but understood and re-applied.